# Android getView method confusion

Tags: java, android

I am doing a `BaseAdapter` sub class for a custom `ListView`.

I would like to know what the parameter, ViewGroup parent does?

Does it refer to the list view or the parent of the XML file to be inflated ?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have a look here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html  and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewGroup` is a parent of your `View`.

Explanation :

When you make an `xml` layout you put your view into some layout(Relative,Linear etc.) That is a parent of your view. And when android call `getView` method he need know, what the parent of your attached View.

`getView` method must return a `View` list item . To do this, we create layout- resource `R.layout.*.xml`. In this method, we must of `R.layout.*.xml` create a `View`, fill it out and send data list . But before you create, we try to use convertView, which goes to the input method. It has previously created View, but unused at the moment. For example, when you scroll through the list of the items out for the screen and no longer draws the need . `View` of the "invisible" items used for new items . We can only fill them with data . This significantly speeds up the application , as do not need to chase inflate once again .

If convertView this time we were not given (null), then we create view.

Comment: Yes but what confuse me is which view? The view the list view is in or the parent of the XML row to be inflated?

Comment: Ah, so lets say my list view is currently inside a LinearLayout. The view group parent is linearLayout ?

Comment: @user3364963 no. ViewGroup - is a LinearLayout in case if you make a view with Layout Inflater.

Comment: I apologise but im still a bit lost. I have a xml row (that is to be inflated) which contains a relative Layout parent and two text views as child. The list view itself is inside a linear layout so what will be the view group parent in this case?

Comment: parent is ListView...in getView method we are setting list item layout to parent view.

Comment: Thank you GVSharma and deathember

Comment: yeah..we are setting one list item layout to list view....this process will continue(no of items that the arraylist have)..each time the custom list item is added to its parent

Answer (score 0):

ViewGroup is a parent of our View, that means our xml view. getView method basically for to working with our view which you would like to show in a one row. So obviously it consists your layout's parent view.

Answer (score 0):

`getView()` method  returns a view for each item (each row of `ListVew`)within the adapter view. The layout format and the corresponding data for an item within the adapter view is set in the `getView()` method.It will be a performance nightmare if `getView()` returns a new `View` every time it is called that's where the concept of `Adapter` came into feature.However, `ListView` recycles the views that are not shown any more, and gives them back through `convertView`.

To understand how `Adapter` works, you can refer the following,

http://www.edureka.in/blog/what-are-adapters-in-android/

http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/